# Pass implicit Ordering[Int] argument to Ordering[T] parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I want to write some mergesort function.

How to supply **Ordering[T]** to **merge** subfunction?

The overall structure of application is the following:

```
object Main extends App {
  ...
  val array: Array[Int] = string.split(' ').map(_.toInt)

  def mergesort[T](seq: IndexedSeq[T]): IndexedSeq[T] = {
    def mergesortWithIndexes(seq: IndexedSeq[T],
                             startIdx: Int, endIdx: Int): IndexedSeq[T] = {
      import Helpers.append
      val seqLength = endIdx - startIdx
      val splitLength = seq.length / 2

      val (xs, ys) = seq.splitAt(splitLength)
      val sortXs = mergesortWithIndexes(xs, startIdx, startIdx + seqLength)
      val sortYs = mergesortWithIndexes(ys, startIdx + seqLength, endIdx)


      def merge(sortXs: IndexedSeq[T], sortYs: IndexedSeq[T],
                writeFun: Iterable[CharSequence] => Path)(ord: math.Ordering[T]): IndexedSeq[T] = {
        ...

        while (firstIndex < firstLength || secondIndex < secondLength) {
          if (firstIndex == firstLength)
            buffer ++ sortYs
          else if (secondIndex == secondLength)
            buffer ++ sortXs
          else {
            if (ord.lteq(minFirst, minSecond)) {
              ...
            } else {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
        buffer.toIndexedSeq
      }

      merge(sortXs, sortYs, append(output))
    }
    mergesortWithIndexes(seq, 0, seq.length)
  }

  val outSeq = mergesort(array)
  Helpers.write(output)(Vector(outSeq.mkString(" ")))
}
```

I want to have general **merge()** function definition, but in application I use **IndexedSeq[Int]** and thus expecting pass predefined **Ordering[Int]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `implicit Ordering[T]` parameter to the outermost function should fix the problem, and passing non `Ordering[T]` arguments will result in compile error.

Scala's sort functions do the same thing: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L635

```
def mergesort[T](seq: IndexedSeq[T])(implicit ord: math.Ordering[T]): IndexedSeq[T] = {
```

Comment: Or you could use the syntactic sugar `def mergesort[T : Ordering]`